# Django Rest Framework Method \"GET\" not allowed Error?

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-rest-framework

I'm doing a CreateApiView class and this method inside class and error is : "detail": "Method \"GET\" not allowed.",

```
class RetractBidAPIView(ListCreateAPIView):
    permission_classes = (permissions.IsAuthenticated,)
    serializer_class = RetractBidSerializer
    queryset = ''

    def create(self, request, pk, *args, **kwargs):
        auction = get_object_or_404(Auction, pk=pk)
        date_now = datetime.now(timezone.utc)
        serializer = self.get_serializer(data=request.data,
                                      context={"request": request})

        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        serializer.save(buyer=request.user, auction=auction)

        bid = get_object_or_404(Bid, pk=current_bid.pk)
        bid.delete()
        return Response(serializer.data, {"detail": "You bid is retracted"}, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

Comment: A `CreateApiView` only implements a POST request: https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/generic-views/#createapiview since a GET is not supposed to have side-effects anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class RetractBidAPIView(APIView)

permission_classes = (permissions.IsAuthenticated,)

def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    auction = get_object_or_404(Auction, pk=self.kwargs.get(pk)
    date_now = datetime.now(timezone.utc)
    serializer = RetractBidSerializer(data=request.data,
                                  context={"request": request})

    serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
    serializer.save(buyer=request.user, auction=auction)

    bid = get_object_or_404(Bid, pk=current_bid.pk)
    bid.delete()
    return Response(serializer.data, {"detail": "You bid is retracted"}, 
                 status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

Answer (score 4):

**In short**: since you change entities (well you seem to delete one here), you can indeed not trigger the view with a GET request.

A GET request is supposed to have *no* side-effects, so that means that the entities remain the same (the same number of entities, and the same values).

A [**`CreateApiView`** [drf-doc]](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/generic-views/#createapiview) thus implements:

> (...)
>
> Provides a **`post`** method handler.

So you can only make POST requests to this view, it does *not* allow DELETE, GET,  PATCH, PUT, etc. requests.

You can for example make a POST request with the [**`requests`**](https://2.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#make-a-request) library, or with [`curl -X POST ...` [wiki]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CURL).

That being said, your implementation looks more like a [**`DestroyApiView`** [drf-doc]](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/generic-views/#destroyapiview). This view handles DELETE requests.

Comment: @TomasAdel: then it is a `ListAPIView` (for a list of objects) or `RetrieveAPIView` (for details of a single object). See the list of APIViews: https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/generic-views/#createapiview

Comment: i know that , but i want wake http status =200 it is 405 now

Comment: @TomasAdel: well as said, for a `CreateView`, the GET method is indeed *not* allowed, since GET is supposed *not* to have side-effects. You need to perform a POST request (405 means that you used the wrong method).

Comment: @TomasAdel: can you edit your question with the view you implemented and *how* you triggered the view?

Comment: class RetractBidAPIView(ListCreateAPIView):
    permission_classes = (permissions.IsAuthenticated,)
    serializer_class = RetractBidSerializer
    queryset = ''

Comment: @TomasAdel: please [`[edit]`](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/56414835/edit) your question.

Comment: See now i did it

Comment: @TomasAdel: how did you trigger the view? How did you make the HTTP request?

Comment: as u saw i added ListCreateAPIView

Comment: @TomasAdel: yes but that does *not* explain what HTTP request you made to the view. How did you trigger the view?

Comment: are you mean this status=status.HTTP_200_OK ?

Comment: @TomasAdel: no, that is the *response* with *what* do you make the *request* here?

Comment: its give me data [ ]